# Dockerfile - copy file to image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to copy file `libwiringPi.so.2.52` from host directory to Docker image on Ubuntu 20.10 x64.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1.21-alpine3.14-arm64v8 AS base
WORKDIR /app

USER root

COPY "libwiringPi.so.2.52", "./"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RPI_GPIO_Tests.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "RPI_GPIO_Tests.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "RPI_GPIO_Tests.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RPI_GPIO_Tests.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RPI_GPIO_Tests.dll"]
```

File `libwiringPi.so.2.52` is in the same location as `Dockerfile`

[image]

and I need it among `.dll` files in `/app` folder inside container.

[image]

Unfortunately I got message:
`COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat libwiringPi.so.2.52,: file does not exist`

.dockerignore file is just:

```
bin/
obj/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the comma between the two filenames in the COPY statement that does it.

Change the statement to

```
COPY "libwiringPi.so.2.52" "./"
```